# Controlling the flow of for loop in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to solve a musical chairs problem. The `list_of_people` is the list which contains the position of the people in the circle. The `steps` variable is the length of the song. So at each `steps` an element from `list_of_people`. At the end there should be only one element.I'm trying to solve this by using a simple for loop. I am deleting the elements in the loop at each `steps` that is at a count. 
I have two requirements:
 1.)When I delete an element I want to step back one position in the loop from my current position. So, when I delete, I set the `integer` to the previous element, so the next time it should start from that position. But that's not working
2.) When the last element is reached i want to restart the for loop from the first position.
I know there is a provision in python `itertools.cycle` for cyclic iteration, but the problem in that is the len() function is not available and i'm breaking my for loop by checking the length of `list_of_people`

```
count=0
list_of_people = list(range(1,inputlength+1))
for integer in list_of_people:
    if count==steps:
       print("Element removed: "+str(integer))
       #Getting the previous index
       previous = list_of_people.index(integer)-1;
       #deleting the current element
       del list_of_people[list_of_people.index(integer)]
       #Setting the index to previous element, THIS IS NOT WORKING!
       #Need some help here!!!!!
       integer = list_of_people[previous]
       count=0
    if len(list_of_people) < 2:#This is the breaking condition
       break
    #I need some help here!!!
    #I need to restart the for loop from the first position
    if list_of_people.index(integer)==len(list_of_people)-1:
    #Set the loop index to zero

    count+=1
print("The remaining element: "+str(list_of_people[0]))
```

Can anyone please help me on this? If there are any mistakes in the code, please forgive me I'm new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is extremely unwise to try to delete things from a list while you're iterating over it. Instead, build a new list, for example with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_of_people = [p for i, p in enumerate(list_of_people) if (i + 1) % steps]
```

An quick example:

```
>>> people = range(10)
>>> [p for i, p in enumerate(people, 1) if i % 3]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```

---

Based on your clarifying comments, I think what you want is simply:

```
def musical_chairs(people, steps):
    index = 0
    people = list(people)
    while len(people) > 1:
        index = (index + steps) % len(people)
        del people[index]
        index -= 1
    return people
```

Demo:

```
>>> musical_chairs(range(1, 11), 4)
[6]
```

Comment: Agreed, but at the end i want a list with just one entry.

Comment: @AdityaCherla What exactly is your rule for figuring out which one entry you want?

Comment: Actually i'm try to solve a musical chairs problem, The list_of_people variable is the postions of the people in the circle, and the steps variable is actually the length of the song. So after every song pause a element in the list will be eliminated.

Comment: I need to find the position number that is the last remaining.

Comment: @AdityaCherla oh, I see - perhaps you should have included that explanation in the question. I have added to my answer.

Comment: What I could'nt do in 15 lines, you did it in 5